# how to to use if-statement to do a command when a condition is met and another command when the the condition is not met

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a list of samples with defined min and max rho values,

```
cat my.table   
SAMPLE  min_rho max_rho
RR26400a    0.1 0.3
RR26400c    0.2 0.4
RR26401a    0.1 0.7
RR26401c    0.5 0.8
RR26402a    0.4 0.7
```

I want to  ask if the focal sample that I am interested is in

my.table  list(if it matches with sample from column SAMPLE in my.table) define a min_rho and a max_rho variable with values from the table and if my interested sample does not match with any sample in the SAMPLE column assign 0.1 as min_rho and 1 as max rho.

so simple example here
my interested sample is RR26400a which is in the my.table list

```
sample = "RR26400a"
min_rho=$(awk -v s=${sample} 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} $1 == s {print $2}' {params.min_max_rho});
max_rho=$(awk -v s=${sample} 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} $1 == s {print $3}' {params.min_max_rho});
```

how can I adjust to run it with if statement and consider both cases when sample is in my.table and when it is not (assign default 0.1 and 1)

Comment: Regarding `I want to write a shell command` - that's extremely unlikely to be the right approach, you should almost certainly just write an awk (or perl or ruby or similar) command instead.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
    min = 0.1
    max = 1
}
$1 == sample {
    min = $2
    max = $3
}
END {
    print sample, min, max
}
```

```
$ awk -v sample='RR26400a' -f tst.awk my.table
RR26400a        0.1     0.3
```

```
$ awk -v sample='xx12345y' -f tst.awk my.table
xx12345y        0.1     1
```

Comment: this works but I want to print min and max as separate variables!

Comment: Then change `print sample, min, max` to `print min; print max`. Again, though, I REALLY don't think that's a good idea as that's a step towards doing whatever else you plan to do in shell when it'd almost certainly be better to just do the next steps in awk too.

Comment: This actually does not work, $ awk -v sample='RR26400a' -f tst.awk my.table gives me default value although the sample is in the list
RR26400a 0.1 1

Comment: As you can see in my answer, my script produces the expected output you provided from the sample input you provided so if you don't get that same result then either you did something wrong copy/pasting my script or your input doesn't look like the sample input you provided. I used tab as the field separator because your code in your question used tab as the field separator - try deleting the line `FS = OFS = "\t"` to see if maybe your separator actually isn't a tab.

Comment: Hang on - if it doesn't work why did you say in [your previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677845/how-to-to-use-if-statement-to-do-a-command-when-a-condition-is-met-and-another-c/677851?noredirect=1#comment1280291_677851) 4 days ago "this works"?